# Ajax not loading data in View (MVC 4)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

My Index View is

```
@model IEnumerable<W.Models.Abc
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("getAbcListA", "Home", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "AbcDetails" }))
{
    <b>Search By:</b>@Html.RadioButton("Searchby", "Name", true, new { style = "width:20px;" }) <text>Name</text>
    @Html.RadioButton("Searchby", "Id", new { style = "width:20px;" })  <text>ID</text>
    @Html.TextBox("Search") <input type="submit" value="Search" class="Searchbtn"/>
}
<div id="AbcDetails" style="width: 35%; height: 130px; display:none;">
</div>
```

and my java script file is

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/getAbcList',
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    })
       .success(function (result) {
           $('#AbcDetails').show();
           $('#AbcDetails').html(result);
       })
       .error(function (xhr, status) {
           alert('from function');
       });

    $(".Searchbtn").click(function () {
        $("#AbcDetails").hide();
    });
 });
```

and my controller is

```
public ActionResult getAbcList()
        {
            var obj = repository.Searchlist();
             return View("_getAbcList",obj);
        }
```

and second function (called by Ajax form) is

```
  public ActionResult getAbcListA(string a, string b)
            {
                var obj = repository.Searchlist(a,b);
                return View("_getAbcList",obj);
            }
```

and my partial view is

```
@model IEnumerable<W.Models.Abc>

 @{
     WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model,
         columnNames: new[] { "FirstName", "SurName", "Date", "Address", "PostCode", "ContactNumber" }
         , defaultSort: "FirstName"
         , rowsPerPage: 15
         , canPage: true
         // canSort: true
         );
    }
```

The problem is that when the page loads first time it doesnt display the partial view and sends an error(from function) which i defined in method. Even if I render the partial view in my Index View

```
<div id="AbcDetails" style="width: 35%; height: 130px; display:none;">
   @{Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Home/_getAbcList.cshtml");}
</div>
```

then the partial view displays the data but the grid goes down the footer tag (body and footer content is being displayed as a background of grid).
I want to load the data via ajax when page first loads and the when User clicks on button then the partial view should be displayed I know I have to define another div to show and current one to hide....Please help.....

Comment: Have you tried wth `@{Html.RenderAction("_getAbcList","YourController")}` your index view

Comment: Thanks. randerAction Or RenderPartial will be called after User click the button BUT my main problem is that data not being loaded when the page first loads.  $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/getAbcList',
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET', doesnt load any data ...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of :

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/getAbcList',
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    })
       .success(function (result) {
           $('#AbcDetails').show();
           $('#AbcDetails').html(result);
       })
```

do like :

```
 $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("getAbcList","Home")',
        contentType: 'application/html; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success:function (result) {
           $('#AbcDetails').show();
           $('#AbcDetails').html(result);
       }
    })
```

Comment: Could you please hav a look at another question while I try this please....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24634399/webgrid-sorting-doesnt-work-onsearch-results